# Kibana Groovy Date Math?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, kibana

I'm trying to display timestamps in a datatable as the difference between now and the event, rather than the datetime of the event.  I've been using the JSON Input feature to script the value as something like "`now-_value`" but "`now`" isn't Groovy and stuff like "`new Date() - _value`" doesn't seem to take, either.  I'm a bit new at Groovy so it's possible I've overlooked something there.

How can I get that datetime difference?  Is there a better source for reading up on how I can best use inline Groovy?  Should I just make it a file script?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer: Elasticsearch supports Joda DateTime out-of-the-box, so `DateTime.now()` can be used for "now."

Unfortunately, my date's epoch_millis become a scientific expression double before `DateTime.now() - _value` can be evaluated, so this date math throws an exception which can't be worked around by casting _value:

```
No signature of method: org.joda.time.DateTime.minus() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Double) values: [1.474109352E12]
```